# HTML5 DnD, event handlers and class indexes

Tags: html, events

Is there anyway to obtain the node list index offset, of a class element, that triggered a 'dragstart' event handler, from within that handler? I require this information so that I may set a data transfer object with that index for use later in a 'dragend' event handler.

```
<div id="div1">
    <div draggable="true"  class="thetiles">goo</div>
    <div draggable="true"  class="thetiles">hoo</div>
    <div draggable="true"  class="thetiles">zoo</div>
</div>

function registerSource() {
    var matches = document.querySelectorAll('div.thetiles');
    for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
        matches[i].addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false); 

    }
}


function handleDragStart(e) {
  this.style.opacity = '0.3';
  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
  /* need to get index of the class element that triggered this
  for the following data transfer object set */
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', ????);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function registerSource() {
    var matches = document.querySelectorAll('div.thetiles');
    for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
        matches[i].addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false); 
        matches[i].addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragEnd, false); 
    }
}

var index
function handleDragStart(e) {
  this.style.opacity = '0.3';

  // Here is your index
  index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(e.target.parentNode.children, e.target)

  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
  //e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', ????);
}

function handleDragEnd(e) {
 e.target.style.opacity = "";
    console.log(index) // Quick confirmation
  }

registerSource()
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/125orcbe/)

Is this what you need?

Comment: Done. Unfortunately, I can't mark it up as I'm not entitled to use that facility yet. Once again many thanks.